# Vuetify : Adding tabs below toolbar not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to use vuetify to add tool bar at the top and hence tabs and greed list. When it comes to the implementation as my code below, I find that only tool bar is presented , but tabs. Would you please tell me what else I have to work with ?

My nvm is 8.4.0
vuetify is good but when it comes to integrating all components all together... it seems not working...what should i do ?

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <div id="app"> 


   <v-app>
  <v-toolbar>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon> 
    <v-toolbar-title>Vuetify Mental Shop</v-toolbar-title>

    <v-spacer></v-spacer>

    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>search</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
  <main>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <router-view></router-view>

 <v-layout>
    <v-flex >
      <v-card>      
        <v-container fluid v-bind="{ [`grid-list-${sx}`]: true }">
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex
              xs4
              v-for="n in 9"
              :key="n"
            >
              <v-card flat tile>
                <v-card-media
                  :src="`http://rcfurniture.com/wp-content/uploads/Boris-metal-base-Chair-Swivel-Chair-1-560x353.jpg`"
                  height="100px"
                >
                </v-card-media>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>


      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </main>  
  <v-footer app></v-footer>
</v-app>

  </div>

</template>



<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      size: 'sm',
      items: [
        { text: 'Extra small (1px)', value: 'xs' },
        { text: 'Small (4px)', value: 'sm' },
        { text: 'Medium (8px)', value: 'md' },
        { text: 'Large (16px)', value: 'lg' },
        { text: 'Extra large (24px)', value: 'xl' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
```

btw, it works on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaEGox
Would anyone tell me why ?

Comment: depending on your `vuejs` / `vuetify` versions, it might be because you didn't wrap it inside `v-app`. See https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/pre-defined

Comment: vuejs : 2.9.1

vuetify : 0.16.7

Comment: but afaik vue latest version is 2.5.2. Are you from the future or im missing something?

Comment: I have installed through Mac and the latest version is 2.9.1

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in v-app as i suggested? What happened if you did? Can you update code?

Comment: code edited , seems working

Comment: Some said using js Components to update the grid. What is that mean ?

Comment: I posted an answer because afaics it solved your problem. (if it solved it then revert the edit from answer, because it's solution to the problem, thus it shouldn't be in answer - I only wanted you to update it in case if my suggestion didn't work)

I don't know what it means to use js components to update the grid (perhaps you mean vuetify components?). I would need more context to see what you mean.

Comment: I mean vuetify components

Comment: For more about updating the grid, see docs:  https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/grid

Comment: I am trying to add on click event for the grid cell and adjust the width and height. What’s your view?

Comment: Please note that comment section is not place for extended off-topic discussions. For your other requirements such as onclick events, see vuejs docs about events and vuetify docs about components you will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your `vuejs` / `vuetify` versions, it might be because you didn't wrap it inside `v-app`. See [docs](http://vuetifyjs.com/layout/pre-defined) for more info

```
<div id="app"> 
  <v-app>
    //...
  </v-app>
</div>
```